# Parâmetro na URL da página

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, restful

Caros, preciso criar uma aplicação pyramid para uso da [API](https://1c22eh3aj8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/challenge/quotes).

1 - “/quotes/< quote_number>” - Apresentar página contendo o quote retornado pela API correspondente ao < quote_number >.

Já sei como criar uma página estatíca em Pyramid, mas não sei como criar uma página que recebe o parâmetro na url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado o conteúdo [desta página](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html), basta você definir o parâmetro na URL entre chaves, tal como `{parametro}` e utilizá-lo através de `request.matchdict`. Veja um exemplo:

```
@view_config(route_name='quotes_number')
def quotes_number(request):
    return Response(request.matchdict['quote_number'])

config.add_route('quotes_number', 'quotes/{quote_number}')
```